# Multiple Colors at a same time in Browser Current window Scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, jquery-plugins

I am working on chrome extension where I want to highlight the position of content in scroll bar Just like 
[image]

Just like image I want to highlight the a section of scrollbar. How do I get the scrollbar and change the color (two color in scroll bar)## Heading ##

Comment: Simply create the scrollbar yourself as a bunch or DOM elements and put the mark elements over the scrollbar area using CSS absolute positioning. There must be existing libraries for that.

Comment: See https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Comment: In Webkit browsers (Chrome, for eg), you can style the scrollbar element using this selector `::-webkit-selector` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar :: the scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-button :: the buttons on the scrollbar (arrows pointing upwards and downwards).
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb :: the draggable scrolling handle.
::-webkit-scrollbar-track :: the track (progress bar) of the scrollbar.
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece :: the track (progress bar) NOT covered by the handle.
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner :: the bottom corner of the scrollbar, where both horizontal and veritcal scrollbars meet.
::-webkit-resizer :: the draggable resizing handle that appears at the bottom corner of some elements.
```

So long as it's a browser that uses webkit, there are a lot of cool things you can do to the scrollbar by using CSS.

Check these pages for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Comment: @jamie Actually I am looking to two color (one for my specific div other for rest) in scrollbar at the same time

Comment: You'll have to give it a try yourself Ayaz, try some conditional operators and see if you can play around with the webkit-scrollbar CSS. Once you have an understanding, come back and ask a more precise question. Good luck! Here's some inspiration: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/